# Continuity of a multi-variable function

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be this function:

$$f(x,y)=(6x+(x^2+4+\frac{1}{2}y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}, 8y+\log(1+y^2)+\arctan(x))$$

Prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

To prove that $f$ is continuous, I separated $f$ into $f_1,f_2:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (its components).

$f$ continuous $\iff f_1,f_2$ continuous.
Both functions are sums of continuous functions, hence they're continuous (is this logic flawed?).

Now I have to show that $f$ is bijective and I have no idea how. Any help?

Comment: You are correct: a sum of continuous functions is continuous. Bijectivity might come from the fact that all involved functions are monotonous on one variable, and maybe you can make some argument relying on the growth of the thing. The hard thing that I don't know if you have considered is proving the inverse is also continuous. Maybe something like the inverse function theorem can help you with that.

Comment: @Evaristo There should be a theorem that says If $X$ is a compact topological space and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then every bijective continuous function $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism. $Y=\mathbb{R}^2$ is Hausdorff, and for each point $x_0$ of $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ I can create a closed neighborhood, so $f^{−1}$ is continuous in that interval. I can do this for every point in $X$, or am I wrong?

Comment: The problem with that logic is that the fact you have homeomorphisms for each closed neighborhood doesn't imply they are going to agree. For example, every surface has for every point an open neighborhood that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but not every surface is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Global homeomorphisms are hard to describe from local ones, that doesn't usually come in cheap

Comment: In this case we already have both $f$ and $f^{-1}$, both going from $R^2$ to $R^2$. We just want to prove that specific $f^{-1}$ is continuous, and if it's continuous for every $x_0$, then it's continuous in all its domain. When we find the homeomorphism in the neighborhood, isn't it just the restricted f?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, of course, that is good enough. Don't know why I didn't remember we already have a fixed $f$, you are right